# HTML5 data-* property in a jstl taligb

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, taglib

How would I implement a custom taglib using JSTL (Java Standard Tag Library) allowing the use of [data-* HTML API](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)? If such feature do not exist how would I simulate this as close as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to create a JSP custom tag accepting dynamic attributes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes.html.

Your tag must be declared with

```
<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
```

in the TLD, and it must implement the `DynamicAttributes` interface.